# Group By query with overlapping dates

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I've got some data with potentially overlapping dates that I need grouped.  First, let me explain the tables:

**tblBusinessDays** - This table has all of the business days, numbered.  Don't ask me why, I inherited it.  Note the day numbers repeat for Friday, Saturday and Sunday.  They do the same thing for holidays.

```
DayNumber   Date        Day
3           12/3/2003   Wednesday
4           12/4/2003   Thursday
5           12/5/2003   Friday
5           12/6/2003   Saturday
5           12/7/2003   Sunday
6           12/8/2003   Monday
7           12/9/2003   Tuesday
```

**tblPends** - This table lists all the pends (times the transaction was put on hold).

```
ClientID    AcctNbr  TransID    InventoryID PendID  PendOpenDT  PendCloseDT 
0           0605161  8378488    1           97455   1/25/2012   2/9/2012    
0           0605161  8378488    1           98051   2/6/2012    2/17/2012
```

The query I currently have in place accounts for records where the PendOpenDt and PendCloseDt are identical for both records, or the Open and Close dates do not overlap.  It's a simple Group By query that captures 95% of the data.  However, I have no idea how to account for records like the ones above, where the PendOpenDt of the second record overlaps the PendCloseDt of the previous record.

Here's what I have:

```
SELECT 
    tblPends.ClientID, 
    tblPends.AcctNbr, 
    tblPends.TransID,
    tblPends.InventoryID, 
    tblBusinessDays.DayNumber AS OpenDayNumber, 
    tblBusinessDays_1.DayNumber AS CloseDayNumber, 
    [tblBusinessDays_1].[DayNumber]-[tblBusinessDays].[DayNumber] AS TotalPendDays, 
    Sum(1) AS [Key]
FROM (tblPends 
    LEFT JOIN tblBusinessDays 
        ON tblPends.PendOpenDT = tblBusinessDays.Date) 
    LEFT JOIN tblBusinessDays AS tblBusinessDays_1 
        ON tblPends.PendCloseDT = tblBusinessDays_1.Date
GROUP BY 
    tblPends.ClientID, 
    tblPends.AcctNbr, 
    tblPends.TransID,
    tblPends.InventoryID, 
    tblBusinessDays.DayNumber, 
    tblBusinessDays_1.DayNumber, 
    [tblBusinessDays_1].[DayNumber]-[tblBusinessDays].[DayNumber]
HAVING (((
    tblPends.ClientID)=[Forms]![frmInventory]![ClientId]) 
    AND ((tblPends.AcctNbr)=[Forms]![frmInventory]![AcctNbr]) 
    AND ((tblPends.TransID)=[Forms]![frmInventory]![TransID])
    AND ((tblPends.InventoryID)=[Forms]![frmInventory]![InventoryID]));
```

The resulting data it returns is:

```
ClientID    AcctNbr TransID  InventoryID   OpenDayNumber  CloseDayNumber   TotalPendDays    Key
0           0605161 8378488  1             2065           2076             11               1
0           0605161 8378488  1             2073           2082              9               1
```

As a result, the TotalPendDays is adding to 20, when it should only add to 17.  In the case above, the desired result could be one record returned with the TotalPendDays equal to 17.

i.e.

```
ClientID    AcctNbr TransID  InventoryID   TotalPendDays    Key
0           0605161 8378488  1             17               1
```

As long as I have the AcctNbr, ClientID and TransID, I can link back and get the rest of the data.

If I have something like this:

```
ClientID    AcctNbr TransID  InventoryID   OpenDayNumber  CloseDayNumber   TotalPendDays    Key
0           0605161 8378488  1             2065           2076             11               1
0           0605161 8378488  1             2079           2082              3               1
```

Then I need this returned:

```
ClientID    AcctNbr TransID  InventoryID   TotalPendDays    Key
0           0605161 8378488  1             14               1
```

If I have something like this:

```
ClientID    AcctNbr TransID  InventoryID   OpenDayNumber  CloseDayNumber   TotalPendDays    Key
0           0605161 8378488  1             2065           2076             11               1
0           0605161 8378488  1             2069           2074              5               1
```

Then I need this returned:

```
ClientID    AcctNbr TransID  InventoryID   TotalPendDays    Key
0           0605161 8378488  1             11               1
```

In this last case, then entire second record overlaps the first, so it doesn't need to be counted at all.

I think this accounts for all possibilities.  Of course, the same needs to be accounted for if the second record occurs entirely before the first record, or partially before.  Or if there are 3 or more records returned.  Basically, any overlapping needs to be accounted for, no matter when it happens.  Or, to put it another way, I need to how how many *distinct* days are pended.

Comment: What do you want it to return? Do you want an entirely different query that returns the sum of that total pending days adjusting for overlapping dates? Because that's just `Max(CloseDayNumber) - Min(OpenDayNumber)` instead of `Sum(TotalPendDays)`

Comment: Well, if I did that and the OpenDayNumber of the second record was 3 days after the CloseDateNumber of the first record, it would return 3 more days than it should.  I need a query that compensates for overlapping dates, but doesn't overcompensate for dates that don't overlap.

Comment: You can easily test if dates overlap by checking the close day number... Please add an explicit desired result, so I can actually write an answer, and include an adequate amount of edge cases (e.g. do I need to account for many entries with some overlapping and some non-overlapping, etc.).

Comment: @ErikA - I've amended the question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is a really complex problem, so I won't fully answer it. The answer could be substantially more simple if the number of pends is limited, and not potentially infinite, or if you just use a VBA solution.

Let's start by limiting the problem (sorry, you will have to do some adjusting to use it): I will provide code that for a certain `TransID`, provide the number of days.

I will also do it in two steps:

Query1:

```
SELECT base.AcctNbr, base.TransID, tblBusinessDays.DayNumber
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT AcctNbr, TransID FROM tblPends) base
INNER JOIN tblPends sub ON base.AcctNbr = sub.AcctNbr
    AND base.TransID  = sub.TransID)
INNER JOIN tblBusinessDays ON (tblBusinessDays.[Date] <= sub.PendOpenDT  AND tblBusinessDays.[Date] >= sub.PendCloseDT
```

This query will return all possible business day numbers for a given AcctNbr and TransID (I assume those are the distinct entries that relate those pends to eachother).

Then, all we have to do is a `COUNT(Distinct)`. Unfortunately, Access doesn't support that, so we have to two-step it:

Query2:

```
SELECT AcctNbr, TransID,  Count(DayNumber)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Query1) q
GROUP BY AcctNbr, TransID
```

Query2 will contain what you're looking for, the distinct number of date IDs within the opening and closing date.